# Google Sheet Custom dialogs With Dropdown Input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, client-server

I want to create a custom dialog box for the user to select the which tab they want to use. Once they have made their selection. The selected tab is changed from hidden to view. By default, all the tabs are hidden.

I managed to get the dialog box pop-up on open. My questions is how do I handle submit event in the html?

```
<select name="Tabs">
  <option value="1">Tab 1</option>
  <option value="2">Tab 2</option>
</select>

<hr/>

<button onmouseup="select()">Select</button>

<script>
  window.select = function() {
  //how do I get the selected element?
  //how do I enable a tab?
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. About "all the tabs are hidden", I think that all tabs cannot be hidden. So can I ask you about your current situation of Spreadsheet? 2. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet by including your whole script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Also note that tab/sheet hidden/visible property is global, i.e., if it changes for 1 user, it changes for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can retrieve the selected element with [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) within the function `select()` as following:

```
<script>
function select() {
 var tab = document.getElementsByName("Tabs")[0].value;
google.script.run.unhide(tab);
google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

The corresponding Apps Script code would be:

```
function onOpen() {
  hideTabs();
  showDialog();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Which tab do you want to see?');
}

function hideTabs(){
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for(var i=1;i<sheets.length;i++){
    sheets[i].hideSheet();
  }
}

function unhide(tab){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(tab).showSheet();
}
```

**Annotations**

- Please mind the comments of TheMaster and Tanaike
- The provided code snippet hides all but the first sheet, since you cannot die all sheets
- This code works provided that sheets with the names '1' and '2' exist within the spreadsheet
- You need to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onOpen` trigger (see: Managing triggers manually) in order to display the dialog automatically when opening the spreadsheet

[image]